# Jolt Transform: Merging objects with more than 1 similar fields and 2 dissimilar fields

Tags: json, jolt

I have a problem something similar to this:

I want to convert the following input:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Product A",
    "price": 10,
    "color": "green",
    "category": "fruit",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Product A",
    "price": 20,
    "color": "yellow",
    "category": "fruit",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Product B",
    "price": 30,
    "color": "blue",
    "category": "vegetable",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

in to this output:

```json
[
 "product_1" :  {
    "name": "Product A",
    "price": [10,20],
    "color": ["green", "yellow"],
    "category": "fruit",
    "id": 1
  },
 "product_2" :  {
    "name": "Product B",
    "price": 30,
    "color": "blue",
    "category": "vegetable",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

In the above input, first two objects are similar, with same name, category and id, so I am merging them into 1 object. There are 2 fields which are different, i.e. price and color. So I am creating array of these fields and putting them into the merged object.

I tried the following:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": {
          "*": {
            "@2": "&[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        // "*": {
        //  "price": "product_&2.price",
        //  "color": "product_&2.color"
        // }
        //,
        "0": {
          "name": "product_&2.name",
          "category": "product_&2.category",
          "id": "product_&2.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But either I can get the array of fields which are different or objects with similar fields. But I am not getting both to work at same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double **shift** transformation might be applied: in the first step; the objects  with the common `id`values are combined within the common array elements, and in the second one; the values for the common keys are combined together. But, still one more step which contains **cardinality** transformation will be needed in order to get rid of the repeating elements for some keys (`name`,`category` & `id` in this case) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@id"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "1": {
        "*": {
          "*": "product_&2.&[]"
        }
      },
      "2": "product_&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "product_1": {
        "name": "ONE",
        "category": "ONE",
        "id": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```